# QT can't display 4k image

Tags: qt

I use QT 6.4 version, after receiving PCIE data in the memory, after that display, but display 3840x2160 image data Image only the top 1/6 have image, but no image below, when I receive 1080p data can be displayed normally.
This is my c++ code

```
newWindow::newWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::newWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pcie_c2h_event0.isplay = false;
    connect(&pcie_c2h_event0, SIGNAL(sig_inform_disp()), this, SLOT(disp_slot()));
    connect(&pcie_c2h_event0, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(slotThreadFinish()));
    m_Qimage = new QImage(c2h_align_mem_tmp,3840，2160,QImage::Format_RGB32);
   if(!pcie_c2h_event0.isRunning()) pcie_c2h_event0.start();
}

newWindow::~newWindow()
{
    pcie_c2h_event0.isplay = false;
    while (pcie_c2h_event0.isRunning());
    pcie_close();
    delete ui;
}
void newWindow::disp_slot()
{
    QPixmap m_Qpixmap;
    if(pcie_c2h_event0.isplay == false)
        return;
    ui->label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    read_pack((char*)c2h_align_mem_tmp,3840*2160*4,0);

    m_Qpixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(*m_Qimage,Qt::AutoColor);
 
    ui->label->setPixmap(m_Qpixmap);
}
```

this is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK00T.jpg

I tried to modify the resolution of ui and qimage, but it still didn't change the image I was hoping to finish

Comment: What does read_pack() do? Why is m_Qimage a pointer?

Comment: read_pack() is the data to read from memory, followed by the number of arguments for the memory. qimage is the memory I want to allocate directly for my image so I can display the image directly from the memory

Comment: And where is c2h_align_mem_tmp initialized? And since you're using threads - how are you sure that the thread doesn't modify c2h_align_mem_tmp when QImage tries to access it (which can be anytime)?

Comment: When I click to turn on the device, it allocates memory for c2h_align_mem_tmp.
The underlying device outputs an interrupt signal, and the thread captures the interrupt signal and then reads the data from memory, so Qimage does not modify c2h_align_mem_tmp

Comment: I did not say that QImage modifies the image but that the other thread modifies the imaga data when QImage tries to access it. Make sure that this does not happen (e.g. by copying the data)

Comment: I don't think this happens because when I receive 1080p images, the display is normal and when I read the black part of the 4k image address memory, the image data read out is not black but other colors

Comment: 'I don't think' - nice try. You should proove that this does not happen - fix your code.